# Liferay FileEntry 0 bytes

Tags: tomcat, upload, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay 6.2 portal ga4 and I have a problem with files added programmatically in document library. When I read a file from tomcat temp folder and save it in document library, sometimes it's correct and sometimes it becomes a zero bytes file.
I upload the file with a jquery script and every time the file uploaded in tomcat temp has the right dimensions. Once I uploaded it in temporary folder, I add it in Document Library in this way:

```
FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, folderUser.getRepositoryId(),
               folderUser.getFolderId(), file.getFileName(), file.getContentType(), file.getFileName(), description,changelog, fileTmp, serviceContextFiles);
```

The statements completes with no error and logs are ok too, but sometimes the fileEntry I have created has 0 bytes instead that the right dimension.
Can someone help me?
Thank you,
smxworld

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There are two different ways of working with DL. First one is to use `DLAppLocalServiceUti` and it doesn't working for me. The second one is to use `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil` and this way solves all problems with zero-bytes-containing folders.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried to use DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil instead of DLAppLocalServiceUtil, but when I use this, I've the following error: "No Repository exists with the primary key 28311"